# MVC3 & MVCContrib grid - Generated Html different between browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I've come across something odd with the MVCContrib Grid.  Using Chrome (or FireFox), when I go to a certain view that uses the MVCContrib Grid, I get the expected results (multiple rows of data).  However, on the same exact page in IE, I'm only getting a single row (the first in the set).

When I inspect the generated html on both sides, Chrome has all the rows, but IE only has it's one.

Here is a list of the dependencies in the project:  Fluent NHibernate, Castle Windsor, MvcContrib, JQuery 1.5.1., JQuery UI, jquery-address, jquery-multiselect

Can anyone make any sense of this?  This is the view in question.

```
<div id="fileList">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column => {
        column.For(x => Html.ActionLink(x.Id.ToString(), "FileDetails", new { id = x.Id })).Named("File ID");
        column.For(x => x.Client.Name);
        column.For(x => x.Status);
        column.For(x => x.ProcessDate);
        column.For(x => x.TestMode);
        }).Attributes(Style => "text-align: center", @Class => "linkGrid").RowAttributes(data => new MvcContrib.Hash(onclick => String.Format("location.href='{0}';", Url.Action("FileDetails", new { id = data.Item.Id }))))

    @Html.AjaxPager(Model, new PagerOptions() { PageIndexParameterName="page", ShowDisabledPagerItems = false, AlwaysShowFirstLastPageNumber=true },
                                new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "fileList" })
</div>
```

New Find:

Sometimes, when I refresh the view in IE, I get Giberish back in the grid.  What was interesting is that the giberish changes.  Sometimes I'll get bits and pieces of garbled javascript, and I even got some giberish about some of the networking hardware on the machine.  I only started getting the giberish when I upgraded to IE9 (hoping that would fix the problem).  Again this only happens in IE, Chrome and FireFox work perfectly.

This is an example of the giberish I see:

"䱾寵釚䕽뾀㘳흷ᛣIntel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000렭蕄��ᇟ₧돨ӘIntel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000렮蕄��ᇟ₧돨Ә "WAN Miniport (IP)擭Ⲫ몣䑳㞶웞ᑚ꫈pWAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000葮瀹ᇞ₝ᴀ降ᱚ VIntel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection뿊ﯩ橙䅴꺝榮퀏蜒VWAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000葮瀹ᇞ₝ᴀ降ᱚZWAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000葮瀹ᇞ₝ᴀ降ᱚ(WAN Miniport (PPPOE)ᩒ踰꿺佉쪹郇ꆖ嚠 "RAS Async Adapter⭾砃䥨䋓㞟縨沨ꨊ:Software Loopback Interface 1葮瀹ᇞ₝満湯捩 BDell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-CardG��⋂籶䓇춤䦥篸苊 Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000G렱蕄��ᇟ₧돨Ә vDell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000G렯蕄��ᇟ₧돨Ә Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000G쾥แ��ᇟᎅ採풩 zDell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000G렰蕄��ᇟ₧돨Ә NMicrosoft Virtual WiFi Miniport AdapterG⋰ꞑૡ䰌侎ᚊց Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000G⋳Ӊ⤐ᇠ䚖☀릹 Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000G⋴Ӊ⤐ᇠ䚖☀릹 Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000G⋵Ӊ⤐ᇠ䚖☀릹 &WAN Miniport (SSTP)韗燸䶍��肬��瀢 (WAN Miniport (IKEv2)覠耣鰚䰨馐羼逪᫃ &WAN Miniport (L2TP)␫麫䘦助摆뮟骓 &WAN Miniport (PPTP)鴬��蝂亱·闓ᣄ㌿ 0Microsoft ISATAP Adapter㳳竹눞䔢꺩뺨ﾝ螅 BTeredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface횀ꎘ忈䊓咚㨎됥釙6Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2ⴼꦡ덁䟩㖷첵崰6Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3萖ᅴ൸䲖ẓ��᧶6Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4ᝲ⪤蒉䄎꾍ꝟ䫺"

Comment: Here's what I would do if I were you: start by removing stuff and frameworks from the code in order to simplify it and try to narrow down the problem. The sole fact that you have listed Fluent NHibernate, Castle Windsor, MvcContrib, JQuery 1.5.1., JQuery UI, jquery-address, jquery-multiselect says that you didn't do anything in order to try to understand what happens and where the problem might come from. So narrow down until you find. If you don't find, show your narrowed down version of the code that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Darin, thanks for the suggestions.  I have tried that somewhat (ie: removing the javascript libraries).  Unfortunately this didn't change my results.  I can't really get rid of Fluent NHibernate or Castle, as they are both used to help retrieve the results.  The correct results are however making it outside of the controller and into the view. What the browser is rendering though is just messed up. Instead of using MVCContrib to render the table, I'll try building the table manually to see how it looks.

Comment: @Brosto, of course that you can get rid of Fluent NHibernate and Castle: just hardcode those results into a simple array in your controller action.

Comment: Darrin, I just tried narrowing the results I was sending to MVCContrib.  I found when I exclude the following column, it works fine.   column.For(x => x.Status);

Comment: @Brosto, great, now, let's move on: what is the type of this property and most importantly what values are there?

Comment: @Brosto, a single char or an array of char? By the way why are you using a char??? What result do you expect?

Comment: @Darrin, it's a status code.  like 'E' for error...  It's just a high level flag to let me know what happened

Comment: @Darrin, sometimes this flag is Null.  I really only set a flag when there was a problem.  It looks like is isn't rendering properly when there is a null value

Comment: @Brosto, try specifying a format for this column: `column.For(x => x.Status).Format("{0}");`. Does this fix it?

Comment: that didn't fix it.  I think what I can do though is change the get-accessor to return a space when null.  It seems like a hack (and weird that only IE is impacted).

Comment: this worked: public virtual char Status { get { if (mStatus == 0) return ' '; else return mStatus; } set { mStatus = value; } }

Comment: @Darrin - I've got to run, but go ahead and post your answer and collect your 50.  Thanks for stepping through this with me.  I'll reward you in the morning when I return...

Comment: @Brosto, does this work `column.Custom(@<text>@item.Status</text>).Named("Status")`? Or this one: `column.Custom(@<text>@(item.Status != 0 ? item.Status : ' ')</text>).Named("Status");`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a nice debugging session we had in the comments section it seems that the problem is caused by the `Status` column on the model which is of type `char` and the problem appear when the value is 0. So one possible solution is to check if the value of the column is 0 and replace with an empty space instead.

Comment: Thanks again for walking through this with me.  It says I need to wait 8 hours before I can award the bounty...